# Show Documents by designation

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

When only director approve/reject documents or in pending then I want to show users that this documents are approve/reject ..

Here is stored procedure which I try

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[spdocuments]
as
   SELECT    
      dbo.DocumentInfo.DocName as DocumentName,
      dbo.DocumentInfo.UploadedDate as UploadedDate , 
      dbo.DocumentInfo.Uploadfile as FileUploaded,   
      dbo.DocumentInfo.UploadedBy as  UploadedBy,
      dbo.Department.DepType as Department,
      dbo.Approval.ApproveDate,
      dbo.Approval.AppoveBy,
      dbo.ApproveType.ApproveType as Status
   FROM         
      dbo.DocumentInfo
   INNER JOIN
      dbo.Department ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DepID = dbo.Department.DepID 
   INNER JOIN
      dbo.Approval ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID = dbo.Approval.DocID 
   INNER JOIN
      dbo.ApproveType ON dbo.Approval.ApproveID = dbo.ApproveType.ApproveID 
   INNER JOIN
      dbo.ApproveType AS ApproveType_1 ON dbo.Approval.ApproveID = ApproveType_1.ApproveID
   WHERE      
      (dbo.Approval.DesigID = 3)
```

When I execute it, it show me results like this

```
╔══════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════════════╦════════════╦══════════════════╦═════════════╦══════════════╦══════════╗
║ DocumentName ║ UploadedDate ║     FileUploaded     ║ UploadedBy ║    Department    ║ ApproveDate ║   AppoveBy   ║  Status  ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════╬════════════╬══════════════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╬══════════╣
║ asdasd       ║ 2014-01-22   ║ CV.doc               ║ amna       ║ Human Resource   ║ 2014-01-22  ║ wajeeha      ║ Pending  ║
║ ERP SYSTEM   ║ 2014-01-20   ║ system admin.doc     ║ noreen     ║ Computer Science ║ 2014-01-22  ║ suman        ║ Approve  ║
║ asdasd       ║ 2014-01-22   ║ CV.docx              ║ amna       ║ Human Resource   ║ 2014-01-22  ║ suman        ║ Pending  ║
║ ERP SYSTEM   ║ 2014-01-20   ║ system admin .doc    ║ noreen     ║ Computer Science ║ 2014-02-03  ║ ayesha       ║ Pending  ║
║ asdasd       ║ 2014-01-22   ║ CV.docx              ║ amna       ║ Human Resource   ║ 2014-02-03  ║ ayesha       ║ Pending  ║
║ kanaban      ║ 2014-02-03   ║ Presentation1.pptx   ║ hira       ║ Finance          ║ 2014-02-03  ║ ayesha       ║ Approve  ║
║ ERP SYSTEM   ║ 2014-01-20   ║ system admin .docx   ║ noreen     ║ Computer Science ║ 2014-02-03  ║ wajeeha      ║ Pending  ║
║ def          ║ 2014-01-22   ║ BISE RAWALPINDI.docx ║ noreen     ║ Human Resource   ║ 2014-02-03  ║ wajeeha      ║ Approve  ║
║ kanaban      ║ 2014-02-03   ║ Presentation1.pptx   ║ hira       ║ Finance          ║ 2014-02-03  ║ wajeeha      ║ Pending  ║
║ def          ║ 2014-01-22   ║ BISE RAWALPINDI.docx ║ noreen     ║ Human Resource   ║ 2014-02-03  ║ suman        ║ Pending  ║
║ kanaban      ║ 2014-02-03   ║ Presentation1.pptx   ║ hira       ║ Finance          ║ 2014-02-03  ║ suman        ║ Pending  ║
╚══════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════════════╩════════════╩══════════════════╩═════════════╩══════════════╩══════════╝
```

in above table recrds two or more times and i want records in single time beacuse in table every record is in single time

Comment: And what results did you **expect** to get instead? What is *wrong* with your current output?

Comment: @marc_s is right.  We can't suggest a solution until you tell us what is wrong, or what "right" would look like.

Comment: in above table recrds two or more times and i want records in single time beacuse in table every record is in single time

Answer (score 0):

In your original question (before edits), you said that you would like all "Approved" and then all "Pending" (unapproved).  You also mentioned that some Approved were more important than others, but I cannot determine which, from the data or your description.  However, this query shows how to get the Approved (only one row for each doc) and then any Pending (which have not already been approved).

Btw, this could also be done using a few more join statements, instead of a union, but sometimes this kind of format is a little easier to debug (because you can comment-out one of the unioned sets or work on it separately).

```
--Approved
SELECT
  dbo.DocumentInfo.DocName as DocumentName,
  dbo.DocumentInfo.UploadedDate as UploadedDate , 
  dbo.DocumentInfo.Uploadfile as FileUploaded,   
  dbo.DocumentInfo.UploadedBy as  UploadedBy,
  dbo.Department.DepType as Department,
  Max(dbo.Approval.ApproveDate) AS ApproveDate,
  Max(dbo.Approval.AppoveBy) AS ApproveBy,
  dbo.ApproveType.ApproveType as Status
FROM         
  dbo.DocumentInfo
INNER JOIN
  dbo.Department ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DepID = dbo.Department.DepID 
INNER JOIN
  dbo.Approval ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID = dbo.Approval.DocID 
INNER JOIN
  dbo.ApproveType ON dbo.Approval.ApproveID = dbo.ApproveType.ApproveID 
GROUP BY 
  dbo.DocumentInfo.DocName as DocumentName,
  dbo.DocumentInfo.UploadedDate as UploadedDate, 
  dbo.DocumentInfo.Uploadfile as FileUploaded,   
  dbo.DocumentInfo.UploadedBy as  UploadedBy,
  dbo.Department.DepType as Department
WHERE      
  (dbo.Approval.DesigID = 3)
AND dbo.ApproveType.ApproveType = 'Approve'

UNION

--Pending
SELECT
  dbo.DocumentInfo.DocName as DocumentName,
  dbo.DocumentInfo.UploadedDate as UploadedDate , 
  dbo.DocumentInfo.Uploadfile as FileUploaded,   
  dbo.DocumentInfo.UploadedBy as  UploadedBy,
  dbo.Department.DepType as Department,
  Max(dbo.Approval.ApproveDate) AS ApproveDate,
  Max(dbo.Approval.AppoveBy) AS ApproveBy,
  dbo.ApproveType.ApproveType as Status
FROM         
  dbo.DocumentInfo
INNER JOIN
  dbo.Department ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DepID = dbo.Department.DepID 
INNER JOIN
  dbo.Approval ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID = dbo.Approval.DocID 
INNER JOIN
  dbo.ApproveType ON dbo.Approval.ApproveID = dbo.ApproveType.ApproveID 
GROUP BY 
  dbo.DocumentInfo.DocName as DocumentName,
  dbo.DocumentInfo.UploadedDate as UploadedDate, 
  dbo.DocumentInfo.Uploadfile as FileUploaded,   
  dbo.DocumentInfo.UploadedBy as  UploadedBy,
  dbo.Department.DepType as Department
WHERE      
  (dbo.Approval.DesigID = 3)
AND dbo.ApproveType.ApproveType = 'Pending'
AND dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID NOT IN
( 
  --omit the pending that have been approved
  SELECT
    dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID
  FROM         
    dbo.DocumentInfo
  INNER JOIN
    dbo.Department ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DepID = dbo.Department.DepID 
  INNER JOIN
    dbo.Approval ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID = dbo.Approval.DocID 
  INNER JOIN
    dbo.ApproveType ON dbo.Approval.ApproveID = dbo.ApproveType.ApproveID 
  GROUP BY 
    dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID as DocumentName,
    dbo.Department.DepType as Department
  WHERE      
    (dbo.Approval.DesigID = 3)
  AND dbo.ApproveType.ApproveType = 'Approved'
)
```